# Entity Framework 6.2 should not automatic pick up my custom DbConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I want to enable SQL logging **explicit** from a single integration-test, without changing the DbContext definitions

What I have: 10+ projects with multiple DbContexts. 10+ test-projects. Many other integration-tests also using EF

What I have tried:

```
internal class MyDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        var interceptor = new DatabaseLogFormatter(s => { sw.WriteLine(s); });

        AddInterceptor(interceptor );
    }
}
```

From one integration test, which is running **explicit** on my machine, is started by running this code

```
        var dbConfiguration = new MyDbConfiguration(fileStream);

        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(dbConfiguration);
```

This works fine. The single test is logging all EF SQLs

But when I run the full test suite (without the one test and without the SetConfiguration), EF will pick up my MyDbConfiguration (to late) and throw an Exception

**System.InvalidOperationException: The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'MyDbConfiguration' type was discovered**

How do I prevent this? I cannot change any app.configs

I want EF to use the MyDbConfiguration, only when I configure it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `Entity Framework` to detect and pick up your custom `DbConfiguration` automatically, you'll have find to a way to bypass the auto detection rules.

By default (without any additional custom configuration) the `DbConfigurationFinder` of `Entity Framework` ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/02104044fae2aca5d3a1f50f55f4af940a3c64a8/src/EntityFramework/Infrastructure/DependencyResolution/DbConfigurationFinder.cs#L23)) looks for a type derived from `DbConfiguration` within the same assembly as where the `DbContext` derived class is declared.

Because you can't change any `.config` files, one way to do this is by declaring your `DbConfiguration` derived class in a separate assembly, away from the one holding the `DbContext`.
Since you're using it for integration testing purposes, you can put it into that test project.